# returns not equal when equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l have a strange problem. when l compare two columns where their values are equal it responds not equal what's wrong around here  ?

```
    df['manual_raw_value'][0:10]
    Out[12]: 
    0       2
    1      32
    2      59
    3    6635
    4       1
    5    5320
    6    1548
    7      34
    8      29
    9     854
    Name: manual_raw_value, dtype: int64

    df['raw_value'][0:10]
    Out[13]: 
    0        2
    1       32
    2       59
    3     6635
    4        1
    5     5320
    6     1548
    7       34
    8       29
    9    00Ô54

df['manual_raw_value'][0:10] == df['raw_value'][0:10]
Out[14]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

for instance the first cell is equal to 2 in both column

Comment: Your last value in `raw_value` shows `00Ô54` this looks like a `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is different dtypes - one is `str` and another `int`.

You can check it by:

```
print (df.dtypes)
```

So need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if need convert column:

```
df['manual_raw_value'] = df['manual_raw_value'].astype(str)
```

For convert all values in `DataFrame` to `str`:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

Or parameter `dtype` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if need convert all columns to `str`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', dtype=str)
```

Or is possible specify columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', dtype={'manual_raw_value':str, 'raw_value':str})
```